# java.lang.NullpointerException after declaring findViewById in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm trying to use `findViewById`, but then a warning appears. I've seen serveral different ways used to resolve this warning but I don't know which is correct when it comes to my code. Does anyone know what the correct way would be to remove this warning in this context?

> Method invocation 'findViewById' may produce 'java.lang.NullpointerException'

**Page1Fragment.java**

```
public class Page1Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    boolean squareState;

    public Page1Fragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        loadPreferences();
        displaySettings();
    }

    public void loadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences pref =  this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        squareState = pref.getBoolean("square_state", true);
    }

    public void displaySettings() {
        if (squareState) {
            getView().findViewById(R.id.blue_square).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            getView().findViewById(R.id.blue_square).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on which part of the lifecycle the fragment is in, it may or may not have had its onCreateView called yet.  In the case that your fragment's view hasn't yet been created, calls to getView() will return null.  Thus, you'll need to check for null.

Comment: If you know where you're calling the getView method, (after the onCreateView and before onDestroyView), you can ignore those warnings.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin True, but making that assumption has led to nasty surprises for me in the past.  It's not always easy to know when a fragment is attached to an activity and it's view has been created.  For example, if you've started an AsyncTask to retrieve some data on a background thread and then go to update the UI, the user may have navigated off of your fragment, and getView() will return null in this case.

Comment: I posted you a clean way to use getView() safety. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a lint warning.

Depending on which part of the lifecycle the fragment is in, it may or may not have had its onCreateView method called yet.

In the case that your fragment's view hasn't yet been created (onCreateView hasn't yet been called,) calls to getView() will return null.

Thus, you'll need to check for null like so:

```
View contentView = getView();
if (contentView != null) {
    contentView.findViewById(R.id.blue_square).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

It's not always easy to know when a fragment is attached to an activity and its view has been created.  For example, if you've started an AsyncTask to retrieve some data on a background thread and then go to update the UI, the user may have navigated off of your fragment, and getView() will return null in this case.

Have a look at the documentation for Fragment on developer.android.com for more information which details the fragment lifecycle.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however checking the getView against null each time you're using it tend to make your code look ugly. One can think that you're not handling the null case when the result is never going to be null anyway.

Comment: Better ugly than throw a NullPointerException because you are not paying attention to how your fragment might be used.  I suppose if you'll be the only developer ever working on that code, you can safely make the assumption that that code will only be called in between onCreateView and onDestroyView, but you'd probably want to write your code assuming others might take over support for it.

Comment: The fragment life cycle isn't a random behavior, if you understand it enough (and it's not that complicated) you'll never encounter any nullptrexception because of that.

Comment: But when you introduce another thread, you've introduce random behavior as is the case I mentioned above in my answer with AsyncTask.

Comment: And checking the null value is the best way you have to overcome that? One best practice is to alway check if the fragment is attached before doing any change to the UI, if the fragment is attached you're good to go.

Comment: It seems like you're arguing about something that is outside of our control.  Android documents that getView can return null: "Returns The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout."  Maybe you can raise this issue with Google if you don't like it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134227/discussion-between-anix-pasbesoin-and-michael-krause).